# Google Script for adding timer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am trying to create a google script which consist of 2 button "start" and "stop". Clicking "Start" will start a timer and clicking "stop" will stop a timer.

I do know I cant achieve this using setTimeout or setInterval, so I used utilities.sleep(1000) . But using this I cant execute the function more than 5 minutes because of limitation set by Google.

Hence I tried using Trigger methods setting at 1 second, but no luck. The triggering is not happening at all.

I am sharing the code below any help is appreciated.

```
function onClickStart(){
  startTimer();
}

function startTimer() {
  removeJobs();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("timer")
  .timeBased()
  .after(1000)
  .create();

  timer();
}

function removeJobs() {    

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (i=0; i<triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }
}

function timer() {
  var seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t,stop_time;

  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var timer = documentProperties.getProperty('timer_result');
  Logger.log('get timer: %s', timer);
  if(timer){
    timer = timer.split(':');
    seconds = +timer[2] || 0 ;
    minutes = +timer[1] || 0 ;
    hours = +timer[0] || 0 ;
  }
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    stop_time = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F7').setValue(stop_time); 
    Logger.log('set timer: %s', stop_time);
    documentProperties.setProperty('timer_result', stop_time);
}
```

Comment: You could put a timer in a sidebar or modeless dialog box.

Comment: As Sandy suggests, this functionality should preferably be executed in a client side javascript, not on Google Apps script servers because triggers are too approximative and normal scripts (as you noticed already) are limited to 5 minutes .

Comment: Appreciate the answer given. Actually for my requirement, I should be able to run and show the timer in cells. Drive sheet url for your reference-> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VXbD80n5_db8oqu3Nx4QfPrwK7bfJQRFZQZACMYXEOU/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

Comment: I believe the above logic should work . Trigger should call the method in the respective time. I wonder why its not calling! Though I increase the trigger to 10 seconds, trigger is not even get called

Comment: Google Spreadsheet is not the appropriate solution here. Spreadsheet is a cloud-based application. Your timer timer would trigger far too many unnecessary server calls. Even if you managed to get it to work today, Google may (and should) consider the practice as abusive and set a more strict limit on the execution cycle. A better solution would be creating a Web page that count the time and report the data back in a more sensible manner. A sidebar or modeless dialog box is essentially a Web page, and can work for your requirement.

Comment: Agree with your answer. Could u pls tell me how to run more than 1 timer simultaneously. I believe you can able to show only one sidebar in spreadsheet at a time. Any thoughts?

Comment: But this approach wont work if google sheet is closed :( Any thoughts for this workaround?

Comment: Why not just have a START and an END buttons which save time stamps, and calculate the time difference?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call timer() from a trigger a unique instance of your script is created and when the execution chain is done it is destroyed. All global variables are removed when the instance is destroyed. So right now every time the trigger is called seconds, minutes, hours are set to 0.

For persistent data between instances use the property service.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

Comment: Appreciate the answer given. I have changed the code (updated in question) as per your comment , used properties service instead of global variable. The problem is that the trigger is not happening after 1 second. The trigger is not even happening atleast once. Is there something wrong with my triggering in code?